# Why $\mathbb Z_p$ has square free unit element?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Suppose $p$ is an odd prime.The number of quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is $3$.
They are $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt a)$, $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{ap})$, $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt p)$,
where $a$ is chopped as square free unit of $\mathbb Z_p$.

But , why $\mathbb Z_p$ has square free unit element ?
And why $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt a)$ does not depend on the choice of $a$ ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, you can generate any $\sqrt a$ from any other one. Can you show why?

Comment: To see why $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has a square free unit element, think about what the connection is to the square free elements of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$.